# JavaScript charts with highlighting and drilldown features

Tags: javascript, charts, highlighting

I'm looking for a JavaScript plugin which would help me to create charts. I would need stacked bar, bar, pie and line charts with drilldown and highlighting features.

Everything I found with these features are just flash and I would prefer using JavaScript.

Does someone have an idea or a suggestion?

Thank you by advance

-Yoann

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into the [google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) api. It's not javascript per se, but it might be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally used the [flot jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) charting library and can recommend it. Very easy to use. You'll recognize flot from the reputation chart in your profile.

I've also used varioius pieces of [Dojo's dojox charting stuff](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2009/03/30/introducing-dojox-datachart/). These take a bit more effort to get going (especially if you're not already familar with dojo) but offer more options/flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably seen amCharts when you found Flash charts with these features. Now there's [amCharts JavaScript](http://www.amcharts.com/javascript/) library with matching functionality.